# Always thin but never fit

Tags: riddle

I am always thin but never fit.
I like all sorts of food, but salsa and cheese are my favorites.
Some have confused me with a crazy person, but I’m not.

**What am I?**

Comment: You are me !!!!  (That description describes me exactly - it is uncanny.)

Comment: @YowE3K well with that name, you could definitely be confused with someone crazy ;)

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil - I may be a freak, but I'm not crazy - at least that's what I keep telling all the orderlies in the asylum where I live.

Comment: @YowE3K why on earth won't they listen! :P

Comment: @YowE3K Any resemblance to persons, living or dead, is entirely coincidental

Comment: Are zombies classed as living, or dead?  Or is a resemblance to them intentional?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are a

> Cracker

I am always thin but never fit.

> They are thin but couldn't be considered 'fit'

I like all sorts of food, but salsa and cheese are my favorites.

> Can be dipped in salsa - See [here](http://www.waitrose.com/shop/DisplayProductFlyout?productId=405466) -  and I think we all know about cheese and crackers

Some have confused me with a crazy person, but I’m not.

> 'A bit crackers' or 'Completely crackers' is a phrase used to describe a crazy person

Comment: Could be "chip" instead, an the last line could be that chips can be confused with crackers since they are similar but distinct foods (and cracker having the double meaning you've already pointed out)

Comment: @tmpearce good point, it could indeed be a similar food.  I'll leave the answer as it is for now

Comment: Chips fit line 1&2 well but not 3. Crackers fit lines 1&3 well but not 2. What now?

Comment: @Rubio you think cracker doesn't fit the first two lines? Cheese and crackers! Crackers are thin! I also think crackers fits cheese better than chips do

Comment: Nobody I know has crackers and salsa  :)

Comment: @Rubio really? *hides salsa behind my back*. How about [this then?](http://www.waitrose.com/shop/DisplayProductFlyout?productId=405466)